# Python 2.7 cmd autocomplete readline buffers seem stale

Tags: python, autocomplete, cmd, readline

I'm using readline based cmd module on Mac OS (and Red Hat Linux) with tab completion enabled. It seems to be working great except for when I introduced my own logic to handle "sub command" completions based on regex matching. here is a simple address book example where I have a tree based structure:

Code:

```
import cmd
import readline
import re

readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")

class Test(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_assign(self, line):
        print line
    def complete_assign(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        if re.match('assign\s+employee\s+name', line):
            return [i for i in ['first', 'middle', 'last']
                if i.startswith(text)]
        elif re.match('assign\s+employee', line):
            return [i for i in ['name', 'address', 'phone']
                if i.startswith(text)]
        elif line.startswith("assign"):
            return [i for i in ['employee', 'manager']
                if i.startswith(text)]

Test().cmdloop()
```

Output:

```
(Cmd) assign <TAB>
employee  manager   

(Cmd) assign employee <TAB>
address  phone    name 

(Cmd) assign employee name <TAB>
last    middle  first   

(Cmd) assign employee name first <RETURN>
employee name first

(Cmd) assign <TAB> <-- This is incorrect. Expecting ['employee', 'manager'] instead
last    middle  first  

(Cmd) assign
```

As you see the difference between first and last "assign " operations, I'm getting different results because the `line` variable in function `complete_assign` seems to get assigned `assign employee name first` instead of just `assign` because of the previous RETURN operation, due to which the completor logic is now matching the wrong regex code block and providing the incorrect completions. Is there a way to "flush" the readline stdin buffer after every operation so that it doesn't remember the buffer from previous `complete_assign` or `do_assign` trials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it, thanks to this article: http://pymotw.com/2/readline/#accessing-the-completion-buffer

While going through the `BufferAwareCompleter` code, I stumbled across this line:

```
being_completed = origline[begin:end]
```

Which made me think that I should be able to use the line indices provided in the completer API to my advantage, and this is exactly what helped.

Since I did not care about the 'stale' part of the buffer, I just used end index to demarcate my line boundary. This did the trick:

```
line = line[:endidx]
```

Updated working code:

```
import cmd
import readline
import re

readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")

class Test(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_assign(self, line):
        print line
    def complete_assign(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        line = line[:endidx] # <-- ADDED THIS
        if re.match('assign\s+employee\s+name', line):
            return [i for i in ['first', 'middle', 'last']
                if i.startswith(text)]
        elif re.match('assign\s+employee', line):
            return [i for i in ['name', 'address', 'phone']
                if i.startswith(text)]
        elif line.startswith("assign"):
            return [i for i in ['employee', 'manager']
                if i.startswith(text)]

Test().cmdloop()
```

Update working output:

```
(Cmd) assign 
employee  manager   
(Cmd) assign employee 
name     phone    address  
(Cmd) assign employee name 
last    middle  first   
(Cmd) assign employee name first
employee name first
(Cmd) assign 
manager   employee  
(Cmd) assign
```